# ¿Como hacer paginación con fetch y pokeAPI?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, fetch

Estoy aprendiendo a consumir APIs con fetch, actualmente estoy practicando con el api de Pokémon (PokeAPI). La cosa es que estoy intentando realizar una paginación por cada 20 pokémons, es decir, que en pantalla se me muestren los primeros 20 pokemons y al dar click en el enlace siguiente se me muestren los siguientes 20 pokemons, logro traerme los primeros 20 pokemons con su imagen y nombre, también logro mostrarlos o pintarlos en el documento HTML, pero tengo el problema de que al dar click en el enlace a la siguiente página para que me muestre los otros 20 pokemons, este me redirecciona al archivo json donde realmente se encuentran los siguientes 20 pokemons, mi duda es como puedo hacer funcionar esta paginación con fetch para que me muestre los siguientes pokemons al dar click en el enlace correspondiente, o para volver a la paginación anterior.

Adjunto código:

```js
let pokemonsList = document.getElementById("pokemons-list"); 
let links = document.getElementById("links"); 


// Llamamos a la API de pokemon con Fetch
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon")
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res=>{
        // Obtenemos y recorremos a los primeros 20 pokemones obtenidos
        for(let i of res.results){ 

            // Realizamos otra solicitud Fetch con la URL especifica del pokemon actual recorrido, para obtener datos mas especficos como la imagen
            fetch(i.url)
                .then(x=>x.json())
                .then(x=>{
                    // Vamos pintando o ingresando la imagen y nombre del pokemon actual que se esta evaluando 
                    pokemonsList.innerHTML += `<div class="card">
                                                <img src="${x.sprites.front_default}" alt="">
                                                <p>${x.name}</p>
                                            </div>`; 
            }); 
        }; 

        // Pintamos los enlaces de siguiente o anterior de la paginacion de los pokemones 
        links.innerHTML = `<a href='${res.previous}'>Atras</a>
                           <a href='${res.next}'>Siguiente</a>`; 

    });
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.container-card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card{
    border: 2px solid black; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px -1px #000000;
}

.card>img{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.card>p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: white;
}

.link{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Poke API</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Poke API</h1>

    <div class="container-card" id="pokemons-list">
        <!-- Donde se van a ir pintando o ingresando los pokemones que nos traigamos de la API -->
    </div>

    <div id="links" class="link">
        <!-- Donde pintaremos o ingresaremos los enlaces de siguinete o atras de la paginacion -->
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo se me ocurre hacer es encapsular tu código en una función para actualizar tus pokemones, como obtienes los url de los siguientes/anteriores 20 pokemones puedes utilizar esta misma función con estos nuevos url. Así:

```js
let pokemonsList = document.getElementById("pokemons-list");
let links = document.getElementById("links");



function updatePokemons(url) {
  if (url) {

    //Reiniciamos pokemones actuales
    pokemonsList.innerHTML = "";
    // Llamamos a la API de pokemon con Fetch
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        // Obtenemos y recorremos a los primeros 20 pokemones obtenidos
        for (let i of res.results) {

          // Realizamos otra solicitud Fetch con la URL especifica del pokemon actual recorrido, para obtener datos mas especficos como la imagen
          fetch(i.url)
            .then(x => x.json())
            .then(x => {
              // Vamos pintando o ingresando la imagen y nombre del pokemon actual que se esta evaluando 
              pokemonsList.innerHTML += `<div class="card">
                                                  <img src="${x.sprites.front_default}" alt="">
                                                  <p>${x.name}</p>
                                              </div>`;
            });
        };
        // Pintamos los enlaces de siguiente o anterior de la paginacion de los pokemones 
        //Boton hacia atrás
        links.innerHTML = (res.previous) ? `<button onclick="updatePokemons('${res.previous}')">Atrás</button>` : "";
        //Botón hacia adelante
        links.innerHTML += (res.next) ? `<button onclick="updatePokemons('${res.next}')">Siguiente</button>` : "";

      });
  }

}

updatePokemons("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.container-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px -1px #000000;
}

.card>img {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.card>p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: white;
}

.link {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Poke API</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Poke API</h1>

  <div class="container-card" id="pokemons-list">
    <!-- Donde se van a ir pintando o ingresando los pokemones que nos traigamos de la API -->
  </div>

  <div id="links" class="link">
    <!-- Donde pintaremos o ingresaremos los enlaces de siguinete o atras de la paginacion -->
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
links.innerHTML = (res.previous) ? `<button onclick="updatePokemons('${res.previous}')">Atrás</button>` : "";
```

Esta función terniaria se encarga de revisar si realmente existe `res.previous` para ver si  se incluye el botón, para evitar problemas de que el usuario quiera utilizar la función `updatePokemons()` sin un parámetro de url definido.